#  How can I get events to send an argument to an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, datagridview

How can I get an event to send an argument to a function? So I can have dataGridView1 & dataGridView2 both using the function dataGridView1_MouseMove?

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
        if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty &&
        !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        {
            // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                   
            DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
                  dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown],
                  DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using this function as well as some others to allow the rows in the dataGridView1 to be dragged and dropped, how can I use this same function for dataGridView2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I use this same function for dataGridView2?

If you want to use the same method, you need to never refer to `dataGridView1` directly.

Instead, change it to use `sender` as your DataGridView, like so:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Use this instead of dataGridView1
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv == null) // Add some checking
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         //...
```

Once you've done this, you can add the subscription to any number of DataGridView instances, and they'll all use the same event handler.